# Is there any memory browser in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, debugging, qt-creator

I can't find it. In the watcher window I can manually type memory addresses but I'd like to see bigger chunks of memory...

If this doesn't exist, is there any other free memory mapper for the Mac (except for XCode and Eclipse)?

Thanks,
rui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this that I've found is to type gdb commands in to the debugger - you can get GDB to dump areas of memory... hopefully there'll be this feature in a newer release!

Answer (score 7):

The latest Git version of Qt Creator (1.3.80) supports memory debugging. You will find an entry in the debuggers context menu as you inspect a variable in the Locals and watchers menu.

Note that currently, there are not snapshots of the Qt Creator Master branch, but they should return in a weeks time. If you do not want to wait, you can compile Creator yourself. If you do not want to get involved with git, download a snapshot from http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/trees/master;

Answer (score 0):

Thomi indicated that QtCreator has no such functionality.

In the meantime, since QtCreator uses GDB for debugging, you could try debugging with [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd) instead (a gdb frontend). In the [DDD manual](http://www.gnu.org/manual/ddd/html_mono/ddd.html#Examining%20Memory) you can read about visualizing memory ranges.